# Qt5 doesn't recognised shortcuts unless actions are added to a toolbar

Tags: c++, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts, qt5, qt-designer

I have a Qt4 application with menu entries with short-cuts (nothing fancy, things like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
 to open files, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save ...). When compiled with Qt5, the short-cuts do not work although the actions are attached to the menu bar.

They work again if I add them to a toolbar though.

Is there an easy way to make it work? I can also add all these actions to the list of actions attached to the main window, but this is a pain and prone to mistake.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? :)

Comment: Nope ... no answer and no solution

Comment: I now tried to build using Qt 5.4 SDK and the shortcuts worked again, so maybe it's fixed now. At least Qt 5.2.1 shipped with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS suffers from this bug.

Comment: Cool, I'll have a look! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue porting from Qt4 to Qt5 on Ubuntu 14.04. The problem is a bug in the current version of the appmenu-qt5 package. There seem to be two practical workarounds:

1. Add the action to the main Main Window (in addition to the Menu of the Main Window). `addAction(<actionName>)`
2. Uninstall appmenu-qt5 until it is fixed.

I was happy to live with the effects of 2, but all users of the application would have to uninstall appmenu-qt5 too.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-qt5/+bug/1313248